# How to you get the response headers with shopify_api gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to implement pagination with the the Rails shopify_api gem (latest version 11.1.0). According to [their docs](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-rest) the next page link is in the response headers.

How do you get the response headers?

Example:

```
orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.all(limit: 250)
response_header = ?
```

You used to be able to use **orders.fetch_next_page** to get the next page but that's not an available method any more (I believe since shopify_api version 10.0.0), and now you have to check the headers.

Comment: Another reason for getting the headers is they also removed the method ShopifyAPI.credit_left to see how many API credits are remaining. That info is supposedly in the headers now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some documentation which I found recently - https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-ruby/blob/main/docs/usage/rest.md#pagination

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.all(session: session, limit: 10)

loop do
  some_function(products)
  break unless ShopifyAPI::Product.next_page?
  products = ShopifyAPI::Product.all(
    session: session, 
    limit: 10, 
    page_info: ShopifyAPI::Product.next_page_info
  )
end
```